# Stop auto-create topic in confluent-cloud

Tags: confluent-platform

In confluent cloud we don't want that anyone can create a topic without any kind of control, we would like to automate this somehow.

However, I don't see anywhere that creation of topics can be controlled in anyway in confluent-cloud.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auto.create.topics.enable` is disabled by default on Confluent Cloud, [and cannot be enabled on Basic or Standard clusters, only Dedicated](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/clusters/broker-config.html#custom-broker-and-cluster-settings-for-dedicated-clusters).